# Jquery conditionally load on a wordpress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

my website is powered by wordpress and I have conflicting plugins.

I found when I remove the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

from the header to load the Jquery libary, the plugin works but all other Jquery elements do not.

I thought a good solution would be to make a condition where Jquery does not load on the page where I am running the plugin to stop the conflict but I am not sure if this is possible or how to achieve this.

Any help on the matter would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just add jQuery.noConflict(); after adding jquery.min.js just like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

From this point you will need to use jQuery() instead of $(), but it will be conflict free.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much- thats solved it. I had tried adding
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
but hadn't realised i needed to replace $()

Thanks!